# Existing state editing in Riverpod / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

How I can manipulate the existing state in `Riverpod`. 'm a beginner about `Flutter` and `Riverpod`. When I try add one to `Order` error pops up and says:

> Error: A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'List'.

```dart
final OrderPaperProvider = StateNotifierProvider<OrderPaper, List<Order>>((ref) {
  return OrderPaper();
});

@immutable
class Order {
  final String product_id;
  final String product_name;
  final int product_price;
  final int product_count;

  Order({required this.product_id, required this.product_name, required this.product_price, required this.product_count});

  Order copyWith({product_id, product_name, product_price, product_count}) {
    return Order(
      product_id: product_id,
      product_name: product_name,
      product_price: product_price,
      product_count: product_count,
    );
  }
}

class OrderPaper extends StateNotifier<List<Order>> {
  OrderPaper() : super([]);

  void addOrder(Order order) {
    for (var x = 0; x < state.length; x++) {
      if (state[x].product_id == order.product_id) {
        addOneToExistingOrder(x, order);
        return;
      }
    }
    state = [...state, order];
  }

  void removeOrder(String product_id) {
    state = [
      for (final order in state)
        if (order.product_id != order) order,
    ];
  }

  void addOneToExistingOrder(index, Order order) {
    state = state[index].product_count + 1; // <--------- Error in this line
  }

  void clearOrderPaper() {
    state = [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening in the code you posted is basically this:

- You are telling it to update the state which is a `List<Order>` with an integer.
- This is because `state[index].product_count + 1` actually equals a number, for example 1+2 = 3.
- So you are telling it, `state = 3`, and this causes your error.

What you need to do, is create a new state with the list of items and the edited item, like this (you don't need to pass the index, you can get it in the function):

```
 void addOrder(Order order) {
//find if the product is in the list. The index will not be -1.
 final index = state.indexWhere((entry) => entry.product_count == order. product_count);

    if (index != -1) {
      //if the item is in the list, we just edit the count
      state = [
        ...state.sublist(0, index),
        order.copyWith(product_count: state[index].product_count + 1),
        ...state.sublist(index + 1),
      ];  
    }else {
       //otherwise, just add it as a new entry.
      state = [...state, order],
     }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I edited `final index = state.indexWhere((entry) => entry.product_count == order.product_count);` to `final index = state.indexWhere((entry) => entry.id== order.product_id);`. This is the i want. Otherwise its stucks at 2 and creating a new product.

Comment: but its gives me one more error. Here is the error: `== Exception caught by gesture  ==
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Order.copyWith (package:neshapp/views/MenuView/MenuView.dart:371:19)
#1      OrderPaper.addOrder (package:neshapp/views/MenuView/MenuView.dart:389:15)` and so on.

Comment: I tried to change `order.copyWith(product_count: state[index].product_count++),` to `order.copyWith(
          product_count: state[index].product_count++,
          product_id: order.product_id,
          product_name: order.product_name,
          product_price: order.product_price,
        ),` but this time `product_count` stucks at 1

Comment: Okay i made it. I changed `product_count: state[index].product_count++,` to `product_count: state[index].product_count + 1,` and its working good right now. Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: Yes, this would fix it `product_count: state[index].product_count + 1`, great, happy it helped! I'll edit the answer and please mark it as the correct one.